# Facebook graph api - How can I allow users to see their friend's score (currently stored on facebook)

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine

I just managed to integrate facebook to my first test app(using unity & facebook sdk 6.0).

Whenever a user logs in and pulls a list of friends for sending invites using...
    `Facebook.MiniJSON.Json.Deserialize(FriendSelectorFilters) as List<object>;`

...facebook already includes a list of friends at the top who have already played the app as well. Is there any way to modify this to include high scores of these friends as well?

I have already managed to POST and store scores using the graph api(using `USER_ID/scores/?score=`), I'm just not sure how to display/include them in the list above (or in any other better way).